# Magento 2: is there any way to set order id incremented by 5 on next order?

Tags: magento2, orders

I need to increase **order id** by 5 on the next order placed.

> **For Example:**
>
> First order id is **#10000007** then the next order placed shall have the order ID as **#10000012** and so on, incremented by 5 on every order.

Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Create a new **di.xml** in this path: **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/di.xml** and put the below code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence">
        <plugin name="chagne_order_sequence" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Sequence" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**

Create a new plugin file under the Plugin folder path: **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Plugin/Model/Sequence.php** and put the below code

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Model;

class Sequence
{
    public function afterGetNextValue(
        \Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if (is_int($result)) {
            return ($result + 4);
        }
        //Check your order prefix here and adjust code according to prefix
        if ($result[0] == 'S') {
            $integerValue = ltrim($result, $result[0]);
            return 'S'.($integerValue + 4);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this only apply for order id. am i right ?

Comment: Yes, You are right!

Comment: @Camit1dk Let me know if you have any issues with the above code.

Comment: i getting this error : main.CRITICAL: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in Plugin/Model/Sequence.php on line 10

Comment: Which Magento version you have used?

Comment: Please don't forget to run the basic CLI command. 
Ex. php bin/magento setup:di:compile, php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: magento 2.3.3, yes i have run all the command.

Comment: error in this line : return ($result + 8);

Comment: Try this return (int)($result+8);

Comment: now order placed with this order id : Your order # is: 8. I have use this line : return (int)$result + 8;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102578/discussion-between-vithal-bariya-and-camit1dk).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your PHP Admin database (I tested on php 7)
2. Find & click on the table called: `sales_sequence_profile`
3. Here change `set` column value into 5 for your specific store.
4. You can find your specific store from `sales_sequence_meta`.

   for ex: `sequence_order_0` value from `sequence_table` column for Default store.

   `sequence_order_1` value from `sequence_table` column for 1st store
5. You can get this `meta_id`(primary key) with `sales_sequence_profile` table's column `meta_id`(foreign key).
6. Change the set value for order, invoice, shipment etc here.

Comment: In which table I need to change for STEP 6 ?

Comment: `sales_sequence_profile` table...Are you getting?

Comment: which one column field i need to update in this table ?

Comment: How many stores you have ?

Comment: it's just a single store.

Comment: Get meta_id value from `sales_sequence_meta` table -> column `sequence_table ` value `sequence_order_0 `.

Comment: Change the `set` value for equallent meta_id in `sales_sequence_profile`table

Comment: are you mean STEP value?

Comment: Oh yes.........